# pysimpleGUI how do i find the current background color of an element?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I know I can change the background color of and element in PYsimpleGUI but how do I get the current background color of the item in the current event
the following will change the item background color to green
`window[event].update(background_color='green')`
however to get the color I am trying something like
`if event.background_color='green':`

here is the while loop

````
while True:
    event, value = window.Read()
    if event in (psg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    dy_pos =event.find('-')
    if dy_pos>-1:
        print(cur_num_selected,numSelAllowed)
        if cur_num_selected<numSelAllowed:
            selectedDate=event.replace('-','/')+'/'+ str(yr)
            window['-SELDATE-'].update(selectedDate)
            window[event].update(background_color='white',text_color='green')
            cur_num_selected+=1
window.close()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have not found the answer to my question but I did get a workaround based on the suggestion from Jason. I add the item on the first click to a list. If the event is in the list then I change it back.

```
if dy_pos>-1:
        print(cur_num_selected,numSelAllowed)
        selectedDate=event.replace('-','/')+'/'+ str(yr)
        if selectedDate in selected_dates:
            window[event].update(background_color='gray',text_color='white')
            selected_dates.remove(selectedDate)
        else:
            if cur_num_selected<numSelAllowed:
                window['-SELDATE-'].update(selectedDate)
                selected_dates.append(selectedDate)
                window[event].update(background_color='white',text_color='green')
                cur_num_selected+=1
    print(selected_dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well are you the one that sets the background color from the start? If so then just create a variable to store the color or you can leave it empty to begin and everytime you update the color make sure you automatically update the variable as well using a function. Then if you ever need to find out the current color you could just run.

```
print(event.background_color)

#or just

print(background_color)
```

Comment: So not set by me but the user. there are 365 items that can be selected. If selected the background and text will change if they re-select an already selected item then I want to toggle it back

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code to understand what it does?
The functionality is a little bit unclear

Comment: sure here is the while loop ```while True:
    event, value = window.Read()
    if event in (psg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    print(event.background_color)
 
    dy_pos =event.find('-')
    if dy_pos>-1:
        print(cur_num_selected,numSelAllowed)
        if cur_num_selected<numSelAllowed:
            selectedDate=event.replace('-','/')+'/'+ str(yr)
            window['-SELDATE-'].update(selectedDate)
            window[event].update(background_color='white',text_color='green')
            cur_num_selected+=1
window.close()```

Comment: sorry looks like it did not format very=well in an add comment part of this thread

Comment: Can you edit it to your question maybe using ``` ``` it'll look better then and i would be able to understand it

Comment: Yes, that's done.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and this was my solution.
PySimpleGUI has a dictionary called LOOK_AND_FEEL_TABLE.
If you know the *currently selected theme* (I think preset is 'BrownBlue'), you can read out the settings for that current theme like this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as gui
gui.LOOK_AND_FEEL_TABLE['BrownBlue']['BACKGROUND']
```

Which in this case would return: `#64778d`
In the same way, you can read out any value from that theme (just replace the index word):

```
'BrownBlue': 
  {'BACKGROUND': '#64778d',
   'TEXT': '#FFFFFF',
   'INPUT': '#f0f3f7',
   'SCROLL': '#A6B2BE',
   'TEXT_INPUT': '#000000',
   'BUTTON': ('#FFFFFF', '#283b5b'),
   'PROGRESS': DEFAULT_PROGRESS_BAR_COLOR,
   'BORDER': 1,
   'SLIDER_DEPTH': 0,
   'PROGRESS_DEPTH': 0},
```

I then used this to define a local list of colors which I then apply to the items to set them back to the 'original' value (before I explicitly change the background color to a specific value).